# which datatype is used for sum(amount) ,that amount in negative values

Tags: java

I was retrieved data from database like sum(amount) it shows negative values like -12447904888.15, that amount column data type is double in sql. In java we can declared that column into Bigdecimal datatype while running this i have an error java.lang.double cant convert into java .math.decimal so how to fix it

```
public List<Chart> showchartPage(String bankname) {
  return applicationLabelDao.createShowChart(bankname)
    .stream()
    .map(data -> new Chart((String) data[0], (BigDecimal) data[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: `new BigDecimal(data[1])`

Comment: Cast it to Double, since it is a Double and not a BigDecimal. If you want a BigDecimal, then change the code inside createShowChart() so that it returns a BigDecimal rather thn a Double.

Comment: The SQL function `SUM()`'s return data type depends on the argument data type!

Answer (score 4):

This here:

```
(BigDecimal) data[1]
```

is a **cast**. A cast means: "I the programmer **know** that the actual type of `data[1]` is BigDecimal. So please, dear compiler, allow me to **use** that thing like an instance of BigDecimal".

Thing is: of course, at **runtime** that type must match what you told the compiler it will be! But your database returns `double` variables to you. And a `double` is **not** a `BigDecimal`!

In other words: when you want to treat something as BigDecimal, than that thing must **be** a BigDecimal. You could try to use `BigDecimal.valueOf(data[1])` instead, that would *create* a BigDecimal instance from the values coming from the database. See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/bigdecimal_valueof_double.htm) for some more guidance.

( and hint: your other cast `(String) data[0]` *probably* works because that data[0] is actually a String object)

Comment: really i can not understood what it mean

Comment: @Nandinip Sorry, I don't know what else to say. You have to be able to express your problem clearly, otherwise we can't help you. Some simple questions: have you **checked** the values in your database? What values are in there, and what values are you seeing in your java code?

Comment: in database values be like -12136274.15 and datatype was double this is for db and in java also we can display same values in a graph

Comment: in question i wrote everthing

Comment: @Nandinip And I answered that question completely. You receive **double** values, and you want to treat them as BigDecimal. That part is **fully** explained in my answer. If it does not work, then "it does not work" isnt a good problem description. Add your **current** code to your question, and add the complete error message from the compiler or the exception stack trace you get.